# @Query returning `Couldn't find PersistentEntity` when querying one column with null value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

*Edited:
I also tested in the version `2.6.4` and still happens*

I just upgraded spring-boot from `2.5.7` to `2.6.1` and I notice a change of behavior in a specific query. I'm trying to load only a specific column in a query, and when it's value in DB is null, it is throwing the `Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.String!` Exception.

This is my code in the Repository,

```java
@Query("SELECT my_column " +
            " FROM mytable  " +
            " WHERE another_column = :secColumn " +
            " AND third_column = :thirdColumn")
    Optional<String> getMyColumn(@Param("secColumn") String secColumn, 
                                 @Param("thirdColumn") String thirdColumn);
}
```

Observations:

- It works fine if the column it DB is not null
- It was working fine with a null value in DB for version `2.5.7`
- If I return the whole entity inside the Optional, it works as expected

Comment: Can be a bug on 2.6.1. Try either 2.6.0 or 2.6.4 instead to see if the problem continues. There is something in Spring Data release notes related https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/releases/tag/2.2.9.

Comment: Just tested in the 2.6.4 and the same exception is thrown

Comment: That would be a regression. Could you create an issue, with a reproducer? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/issues/new

Comment: @JensSchauder sure, I just have done https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/issues/1190

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug in Spring Data JDBC](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/issues/1167) which was already reported (and fixed).

The next set of releases should include that fix.